# How to conditionally assign a type to a reference

Tags: rust

I have been playing with Rust this afternoon and decided to write a simple hashing tool that can do all major digesting algorithms.

I'm trying to do something like this (intent should be obvious):

```
let mut hasher;
match alg {
    "md5" => { hasher = Md5::new() }
    "sha1" => { hasher = Sha1::new() }
    _ => { println!("Algorithm not implemented");
           process::exit(1); }
}
hash_file(&file_name, &mut hasher).unwrap();
```

When compiling the above, due to the first match, it assumes that hasher is of type `Md5` and fails when in the `"sha1"` match branch, it tries to assign a `Sha1` type.  All of the types I intend to use in this match statement are implementers of the trait `Digest` so I feel like there should be a way to do this.

I tried:

```
let mut hasher: Digest;
```

But that didn't work either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use [trait objects](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/trait-objects.html). Your example would then look roughly like this:

```
let mut hasher;
match alg {
    "md5" => { hasher = Box::new(Md5::new()) as Box<Digest>}
    "sha1" => { hasher = Box::new(Sha1::new()) as Box<Digest>}
    _ => { println!("Algorithm not implemented");
           process::exit(1); }
}
hash_file(&file_name, &mut hasher).unwrap();
```

This will only work under certain conditions (for example, the trait has to be [object safe](http://huonw.github.io/blog/2015/01/object-safety/)), but I think it's the only way to do what you want.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to [creating a boxed trait object](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35260549/155423), you can also have a reference to a trait object. This avoids a heap allocation:

```
trait Hasher { fn hash(&self) -> u8 { 42 } }

struct Md5;
struct Sha1;

impl Hasher for Md5 {}
impl Hasher for Sha1 {}

fn hash_it(which: &str) {
    let (md5, sha1);

    let hasher: &Hasher = match which {
        "md5" => {
            md5 = Md5;
            &md5
        },
        "sha1" => {
            sha1 = Sha1;
            &sha1
        },
        _ => unreachable!("Nope"),
    };

    hasher.hash();
}

fn main() {
    hash_it("md5");
    hash_it("sha1");
}
```

Note that each implementor is only created in the appropriate match arm, so you aren't doing more work than you need to.

Comment: If I saw this code in C or C++, I would immediately reject it at code review because taking a reference to a potentially uninitialized value is fraught with peril (next maintenance operation, it'll blow up). Here I look at it and just nod. It really is so liberating when you can trust the language/compiler.

Comment: @MatthieuM. Ain't that the truth! I'm always happy to remember that the variables don't need to be `mut` in this case, as well.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the replies.  I got it to work with Box which I still don't completely understand but I'm going to read up on later.  Final working code:

```
fn process_hash(file_name: &str, alg: &str) {
    let valid_algorithms: Vec<&str> =
        vec!["md5", "sha1", "sha224", "sha256", "sha384", "sha512", "sha512224",
             "sha512256", "blake2b-64", "ripemd160", "whirlpool"];
    let mut hasher: Box<Digest>;
    match alg {
        "md5" => { hasher = Box::new(Md5::new()) }
        "sha1" => { hasher = Box::new(Sha1::new()) }
        "sha224" => { hasher = Box::new(Sha224::new()) }
        "sha256" => { hasher = Box::new(Sha256::new()) }
        "sha384" => { hasher = Box::new(Sha384::new()) }
        "sha512" => { hasher = Box::new(Sha512::new()) }
        "sha512224" => { hasher = Box::new(Sha512Trunc224::new()) }
        "sha512256" => { hasher = Box::new(Sha512Trunc256::new()) }
        "blake2b-64" => { hasher = Box::new(Blake2b::new(64)) }
        "ripemd160" => { hasher = Box::new(Ripemd160::new()) }
        "whirlpool" => { hasher = Box::new(Whirlpool::new()) }
        _ => { println!("Algorithm not implemented");
               println!("Valid choices: {}", valid_algorithms.join(" "));
               process::exit(1); }
    }
    hash_file(&file_name, &mut *hasher).unwrap();
}
```

Comment: Btw. You can make the match a bit less noisy by assigning the match result to `hasher` [like this](https://gist.github.com/fhartwig/d502370790fc3aa36450) (gist because comments don't have enough space).